# How to discriminate between SSH and SCP for QoS in OpenWRT (and other systems)?

Tags: ssh, scp, openssh, openwrt, qos

I regularly upload large amounts of data using SCP through my DSL upstream connection, which is limited to 1kbit/s. While I really want interactive SSH sessions to have highest priority, simply setting SSH to the highest priority renders the connection unusable during SCP uploads.

How can I differentiate between SSH and SCP for Quality of Service settings, especially in OpenWRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least OpenSSH sets different TOS bits (`0x16` for interactive sessions, `0x08` for bulk transfers), as [discussed on quora](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-identify-interactive-SSH-but-not-SCP-packets).

This can be easily exploited using rules that match those bits. It seems the highest matching QoS takes effect, make sure not to have a general rule for port 22/SSH around: OpenWRT by default ships a rule matching SSH and DNS together. For there rules, I used the overlapping DSCP values of `0x04` and `0x02` as proposed in the quora post linked above.

```
config classify                                          
        option target           "Priority"                   
        option ports            "22"                     
        option dscp             0x04                     
        option comment          "ssh"      
config classify                                          
        option target           "Bulk"                   
        option ports            "22"                     
        option dscp             0x02                     
        option comment          "scp"
```

For "naked" iptables setups, these are the resulting rules (the `-m dscp --dscp 0x04` and `-m dscp --dscp 0x02` arguments are the most interesting parts):

```
-A qos_Default_ct -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x0/0xf -m tcp -m multiport --ports 22 -m dscp --dscp 0x04 -m comment --comment ssh -j MARK --set-xmark 0x11/0xff
-A qos_Default_ct -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x0/0xf -m tcp -m multiport --ports 22 -m dscp --dscp 0x02 -m comment --comment scp -j MARK --set-xmark 0x44/0xff
```

*Be sure to restart the SCP transfer after reloading the QoS settings using `/etc/init.d/qos restart`. QoS settings are only applied to new streams.*

Before applying those rules (with a single SSH "priority" rule), I had a ping of around 200ms during SCP uploads; with the rule applied it came down to 70-100ms (compared to 30ms through an idle line).